# Best way to represent games in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have games and want to store them in DynamoDB. I later query these games 1) by id (get a specific game given the id) and 2) day (get me all games for a day).

Currently I have the id as the HASH_KEY but this won't work for the 2nd query.

What do you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Look into Global Secondary Indexes

Comment: So is this the best way? I can use a GSI (I was thinking of doing the same but wanted to confirm). thx

Comment: GSI's aren't without their tradeoffs, but if you have a set of data you want to access multiple ways that is what they provide.  I'd recommend watching this video to get some good examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmHGrONoif4

Answer (score 1):

One best practice for DynamoDB is to use rolling time series tables. You can create a new DynamoDB table for each time period (daily, weekly, etc) and insert new data into those tables. In this manner, you limit the total data in a single table, and can easily retrieve the query you mention by scanning a daily table. Additionally, you can dial down write throughput once a time frame is over and adjust the read throughput to your application needs.

If you need to look up games by user, you can have a separate table that maps users to games and tells you which tables to look them up in.